# How can I ignore a namespace and its tests in Team City?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have some unit tests in

```
     some.namespace.database {

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class Config{ }

    [TestFixture]
    public class SomeTests{

       [Test]
       public void MyTest(){}
    }
}
```

How can I tell team city to ignore everything in `some.namespace.database {}` ?

I can use Ignore attribute on tests, but I want to explicit exclude a namespace from being run.

Thanks for any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break these tests into their own project, and then leave that off the test assemblies list. Not ideal, but I believe this would work.  (If you're including the assemblies by wildcards, you could add this to your exclude list instead.)

Answer (score 2):

As Paul Phillips suggested, break those test into their own project. Or you can mark them with a special NUnit category then add the category to "NUnit categories exclude".